# Click image in separate gender

Tags: reactjs

How do I click on one men's or woman's clothing image to open different clothing products on another page in ReactJS using React Router? I searched Google and found nothing.

Im using Map to loop each clothing product for men or women only.

Comment: the next time, you can share more detail your problem and code for our approach

Comment: @Per you should not have answered this bad question.

Comment: @Arkellys let it go! I just wanna feedback for author , it'll be better for next time , thank you

Comment: Im learning with reactJS that you cannot say "let it go". If you don't want to support me, then don't send this message there. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

example below maybe help you fix your issue:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/mens-clothing">Men's Clothing</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/womens-clothing">Women's Clothing</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <Route path="/mens-clothing" component={MenClothingPage} />
        <Route path="/womens-clothing" component={WomenClothingPage} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```